# flash export won't include images imported into stage or library

Tags: flash, import, bitmap, movieclip

I have a flash file (banner ad) that uses some jpgs that I imported onto the stage.  When I publish the file... It won't include the images.  If the images are in the same folder as the swf.. it will work.  However, just the SWF on its own will not display the images.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

are the jpgs in any special formats? (CMYK instead of RGB, if so... convert to RGB)
are your jpgs on a guide layer? (if so, move'em out of it)
If it works with the images in the same folder, it sounds like the images may be loaded dynamically. Are you looking to embed them in the SWF or load them?